# inputタグのsubmitボタンを押下しても無反応な理由を知りたい

Tags: html

formタグ内にdivタグを入れて、この中にsubmitボタンを配置しています。
標題のとおり、無反応な理由を知りたいですが、formタグとinputタグのどちらに問題があるのかも掴めていないです。
初歩的なことと思いますが、考えられる要因を教えてくださいませんか？

先ほどスクリーンショットで貼り付けた画像は削除させて頂き、
HTML・JSそのものを以下に貼り付けさせて頂きました。引き続きご支援よろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>申請画面</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Calendar by Jquery  #1:DatePicker  #2:For_Ja  #3:採用JS  #4:DatePicker_CSS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/datepicker-ja.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 id="logo"><img src="img/common_header_logo001.gif" width="254" heigth="25" alt=""></h1>
            <form method="get" action="entry.php">
                <div class="ctrl">
                    <input type="radio" name="act" value="0" checked>登録
                    <input type="radio" name="act" value="1">更新
                    <select name="idlist">
                    </select><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="更新"><br><br>
                </div>
                <table>
                    <tr class="appHeader">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>コード</th>
                        <th>品名</th>
                        <th>容量</th>
                        <th>保冷区分</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>ロット№</th>
                        <th>数量</th>
                        <th>単価</th>
                        <th>金額</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="VSlide">
                <table>
                    <tr class="appLineDummy">
                        <td><button class="cdsrch" type="button"><img src="img/検索.png" width="19" heigth="19" alt=""></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cd" required style="width:45px;"></td>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><button class="lotsrch" type="button"><img src="img/検索.png" width="19" heigth="19" alt=""></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lot" disabled="disabled" style="width:150px;"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="amount" style="width:45px;"></td>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><label></label></td>
                        <td><button class="rowins" type="button">+</td>
                        <td><button class="rowdel" type="button">-</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                <table>
                    <tr class="appFooter">
                        <td colspan="6">出荷日：<input id="calendar" type="text"></td>
                        <td class="footercol2" colspan="2">経費負担部所：<select name="idlist"></select></td>
                        <td class="footercol3">合計</td>
                        <td class="footercol4"><label>0</label></td>
                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

【JS】

```
$(function() {
    // カレンダ表示
    $('#calendar').datepicker();


    // 品名コード検索画面（winOpenとセットで利用）
    //$('.cdsrch').click(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".cdsrch", function(e) {
        winOpen('cdselect.php', 600, 900);
        return false;
    });
    // ロット検索画面
    //$('.lotsrch').click(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".lotsrch", function(e) {
        winOpen('lotselect.php', 600, 900);
        return false;
    });
    function winOpen(url, width, height) {
        if (width > 800) {
            width = 800;
        }
        if (height > 600) {
            height = 600;
        }
        window.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=' + width + ', height=' + height);
    }


    // テーブル行追加
    var $dummyRow = $("tr.appLineDummy");

    $(document).on("click", ".rowins", function(e) {
        var $row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        addRowBelow($row);
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".rowdel", function(e) {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        $(row).remove();
    });
    function addRowBelow($ele) {
        var $newRow = $dummyRow.clone();
        $newRow.removeClass("appLineDummy");
        $newRow.insertAfter($ele);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            addRowBelow($dummyRow);
        }
    });




    /* テーブル行追加
    $('.rowins').click(function() {
        var $torow = $(this).closest("tr");
        $copyrow = $("tr.appLineDummy");
        var $newRow = $copyrow.clone(true);
        $newRow.removeClass("appLineDummy");
        $newRow.insertAfter($torow);
    });             //
    // テーブル行削除
    $('.rowdel').click(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        $(row).remove();
    }); */

    // 数量入力枠を数字のみ受け付けるように
    $("input[name='amount']").on('keydown', function(e) {
        var k = e.keyCode;
        if(!((k >= 48 && k <= 57) || (k >= 96 && k <= 105) || k == 32 || k == 8 || k == 9 || k == 46 || k == 39 || k == 37)) {
                    return false;
        }
    });

    // 数量入力枠にカンマを自動挿入
    $("input[name='amount']").on('blur', function(){
        var num = $(this).val();
        num = num.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+$)/g, '$1,');
        $(this).val(num);
    });
    // 数量入力枠からカンマを除去（カーソルあたった時）
    $("input[name='amount']").on('focus', function(){
        var num = $(this).val();
        num = num.replace(/,/g, '');
        $(this).val(num);
    });

});
```

Comment: htmlはスクリーンショットではなく、テキストで全部記述をするようにしてください。またJavaScriptも影響する可能性がありますので、上記スクリーンショットに記述とtest.jsも貼り付けてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブラウザー上の開発者ツールでクリック時にどのように表示されていますでしょうか？ 特にネットワーク周り、意図通りの`GET`リクエストが行われているか確認してください。
意図通りにリクエストされている場合は次にWebサーバーのアクセスログを確認してください。

なお、`<form>`～`</form>`間に大量の`<input>`が存在するように見受けられますが、それらすべてを送信するのは意図通りでしょうか？

Comment: sayuri様　大変申し訳ございません。inputタグ内のあるテキストボックスに必須入力のrequired属性を設定していて、昨日相談させて頂いた行複写の件で全行の当該テキストボックスに値を入れない限り、ブラウザがサーバアクセスを拒んでいたようです。すみません、これでなんとか進展した．．．と思います。ありがとうございました。